# Why $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\frac{P(iy)}{Q(iy)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

While reading about the concept of $L$-stability I came across a result that said that for a rational (complex) function $R(z)=P(z)/Q(z)$ where $P,Q$ are polyomials we have $$\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\frac{P(iy)}{Q(iy)},$$ where $y$ is real and $i^2=-1$. In words, the limit when moving on the real axis to infinity is the same as the limit when moving to infinity on the imaginary axis. I don't really know much about complex analysis but I was wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Because the $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} R(z)=a/b$ where $a$ is the leading coefficient of $P$ and $b$ is the leading coefficient of $Q$ given that $deg(P)=deg(Q)$. It is not relevant in which direction you move to infinity as long as the absolute value blows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\deg P(z)>\deg Q(z)$, both limits are infinity. If $\deg P(z)<\deg Q(z)$, both limits are $0$. Otherwise, both limits are equal to$$\frac{\text{leading coefficient of }P(z)}{\text{leading coefficient of }Q(z)}.$$More generally, in each case there is the limit $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$, and so the direction that you take as you go to $\infty$ doesn't matter.